# Android Google Place API java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

Im trying to add the name of the resturaunt and the category onto a card view via custom adapter. How ever when ever i run the program i keep getting a java null pointer exception. Im a little bit startled by this, i have been looking through the web but have found no luck. Thanks in advance!

```
 //Main:

package com.example.rifatrashid.compass;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Rifat Rashid on 2/23/2015.
*/
public class chooseactivity extends ActionBarActivity{
private ListView listView1;
ArrayList<Places> venuesList;
final String GOOGLE_KEY = "AIzaSyD72cNSZ6PoMFwvDe-ihUDNcTrAnuMynuE";
TextView t1;
final String latitude = "40.7463956";
final String longitude = "-73.9852992";
PlacesAdapter adapter1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chooselocation);
    new googleplaces().execute();

    /*Places place_data[] = new Places[]{
      new Places("Lunch", "Mandarin Cuisine"),
      new Places("Brunch", "Fredmeyer"),
      new Places("Supplies", "Target")
    };
    */
    /*
   PlacesAdapter adapter = new PlacesAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, place_data);
   listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    */
}
class googleplaces extends AsyncTask<View, Void, String> { //Line54
    String temp;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(View... urls) {
        temp = makeCall("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&radius=100&sensor=true&key=" + GOOGLE_KEY);
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (temp == null) {
            //Error coce exception
        } else {
            venuesList = (ArrayList<Places>) parseGoogleParse(temp);
            List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<>();
            //List<Places> gPlace = new ArrayList<>();
            Places[] place_data = new Places[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < venuesList.size(); i++) {
                //listTitle.add(i, venuesList.get(i).getName() + "\nOpen Now: " + venuesList.get(i).getOpenNow() + "\n(" + venuesList.get(i).getCategory() + ")");
                new Places(venuesList.get(i).getCategory().toString(), venuesList.get(i).getName().toString()); //Line77
                //gPlace.add(new Places(venuesList.get(i).getCategory(), "y"));
            }
             adapter1 = new PlacesAdapter(chooseactivity.this, R.layout.listview_item_row, place_data);
            listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        }
    }
}
public static String makeCall(String url) {

    // string buffers the url
    StringBuffer buffer_string = new StringBuffer(url);
    String replyString = "";

    // instanciate an HttpClient
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // instanciate an HttpGet
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(buffer_string.toString());

    try {
        // get the responce of the httpclient execution of the url
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

        // buffer input stream the result
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        // the result as a string is ready for parsing
        replyString = new String(baf.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(replyString);

    // trim the whitespaces
    return replyString.trim();
}

private static ArrayList<Places> parseGoogleParse(final String response) {
    ArrayList<Places> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        if (jsonObject.has("results")) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Places poi = new Places();
                if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("name")) {
                    poi.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("name"));
                    poi.setRating(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("rating", " "));

                    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("opening_hours")) {
                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("opening_hours").has("open_now")) {
                            if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("opening_hours").getString("open_now").equals("true")) {
                                poi.setOpenNow("YES");
                            } else {
                                poi.setOpenNow("NO");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        poi.setOpenNow("Not Known");
                    }
                    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("types")) {
                        JSONArray typesArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("types");

                        for (int j = 0; j < typesArray.length(); j++) {
                            poi.setCategory(typesArray.getString(j) + ", " + poi.getCategory());
                        }
                    }
                }
                temp.add(poi);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ArrayList<Places>();
    }
    return temp;

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

Heres my Places Class:

```
package com.example.rifatrashid.compass;

/**
 * Created by Rifat Rashid on 2/23/2015.
 */
public class Places {
public String category;
public String name;
public String rating;
public String open;
public Places(){
    super();
}

public Places(String category, String name){
    super();
    this.category = "";
    this.name = "";
    this.rating = "";
    this.open = "";

}
public String getCategory(){
    return  category;
}
public String getOpen(){
    return open;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public void setOpenNow(String openNow) {
    this.open = openNow;
}

public void setCategory(String s) {
}

public String getOpenNow() {
    return open;
}
}
```

My custom adapter class:

```
package com.example.rifatrashid.compass;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Created by Rifat Rashid on 2/23/2015.
*/
public class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Places[] data;
//List<Places> data;


public PlacesAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Places[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}




public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View row = convertView;
    PlacesHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new PlacesHolder();

        holder.titleTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.placeTitle);
        holder.sub = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.placeCategory);


        row.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (PlacesHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Places place = data[position];
    holder.titleTxt.setText(place.getName());
    holder.sub.setText(place.getCategory());
    return row;
}

static class PlacesHolder{
    TextView titleTxt, sub;
}
}
```

Error:

```
02-26 17:05:30.530    9757-9757/com.example.rifatrashid.compass E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rifatrashid.compass, PID: 9757
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.rifatrashid.compass.chooseactivity$googleplaces.onPostExecute(chooseactivity.java:77)
        at com.example.rifatrashid.compass.chooseactivity$googleplaces.onPostExecute(chooseactivity.java:54)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: show in your code which line is chooseactivity line 77

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira just added the line numbers like you requested!

Answer (score 2):

As your error log says, you have a problem with a line in your onPostExecute method in your googleplaces class of your chooseactivity activity.  (Line 77)

Specifically, one of the elements that you're trying to call toString() on is null.

```
new Places(venuesList.get(i).getCategory().toString(), venuesList.get(i).getName().toString()); //Line77
```

To fix the error (but not necessarily your process), wrap this in an if statement that checks to see if the element is null.  Like this, for example:

```
if (venuesList.get(i) != null && venuesList.get(i).getCategory() != null && venuesList.get(i).getName() != null) {
    new Places(venuesList.get(i).getCategory().toString(), venuesList.get(i).getName().toString()); //Line77
}
```

Now this won't actually fix your code, just prevent this error from occurring.  What you should really do is in Android Studio, put a breakpoint on Line 77 so that when you debug, you can see exactly which element is null and track back why that might be the case and how you can intercept it in the future.